# How to load a html file on tab click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created nav-pills using bootstrap. When I click on a particular link, I want to load a html file.

This is my html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li class="active"><a class="trigger" data-toggle="pill" href="createarray.html">Creation</a></li>
<li><a class="trigger" data-toggle="pill" href="insertarray.html">Insertion</a></li>
<li><a class="trigger" data-toggle="pill" href="deletearray.html">Deletion</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="create" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <h3>Creating an Array</h3>
 </div>
 <div id="insert" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Inserting</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript for loading createarray.html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trigger').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var link = $(this).attr("href");
           $('.create').load(link);
    });
});
```

Comment: `create` is an ID so your selector must be `$(#create)` ... voting to close as typo?

Comment: `$('#create').load(link, function(){
                      console.log('callback success');
                  });`  Add a call back function to gauge the result of your click event.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.trigger').click(function(e){
var link = $(this).attr("href");
           $('#create').load(link);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is working. But when i click on "insertion" insertarray.html is loading and when i click back creation it is not loading again.

Comment: Your question is not clear but it seems that you are having a problem because you are using `preventDefault`. See the updated answer.